# Is there a Way to Run a Docker Image without installing it in server?

Tags: docker, php, sysadmin

I have created a Laravel application that I tried to deploy in a shared host (other apps running). It creates a conflict with the other project at the point to observe CSRF interferences at the other applications. So I decided to containerize my application. But when I log into the server there is no tool to manage those containers.

How can I deploy a containerizer docker app into my server? Does there exist some tool that I can put inside a folder with the docker image and runs exposing the port to work?

My server has cpanel but not WHM.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run containers as a regular user using [podman](https://podman.io/) (buzzword: [rootless](https://github.com/containers/podman#rootless)).

Note that while podman is based on the same OCI standard as docker, there are some differences in the details. For example, healthchecks are specific to docker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can put it in a folder because the docker management tools require that docker be installed on the server. You should check to see if your server has Docker installed. Because you mentioned having only cPanel access and no WHM, I assume you don't have root access to the server (shared server hosting does not allow root access). Also, I believe cPanel does not include docker by default, and even if it does, installation requires root access.

You may check some StackOverflow responses and guides for "Publishing Laravel on a cPanel Shared Hosting" here: [How-to-deploy-docker-containers-to-shared-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887426/how-to-deploy-docker-containers-to-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 0):

Well, without access to CLI and root (to install the engine) it is virtually next to impossible. It doesn't matter if you want docker, podman, or even runc (OCI), you simply don't have it.

The suggestion can be to run a server with the full root access, from Digital Ocean, OVH (there is many providers), so you can work with containers.